# JWT x5c token validation .net core

Tags: c#, jwt, token, .net-6.0

I would like to validate a JWS token with "alg": "ES256", "x5c" header fields only.

x5c field contain 3 certificates. I'm able to load them but .net return a IDX10503 error telling me kid field is missing.

here is my code :

```
var handler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);

var x5cList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jwtSecurityToken.Header.X5c);

var certs = ValidateCertificate(x5cList.ToList());
var keys = certs.Select(cert => new X509SecurityKey(cert)).ToList();

SecurityToken validatedToken;
handler.ValidateToken(jwtSecurityToken.RawData, new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKeys = keys,
    TryAllIssuerSigningKeys = true,                    
}, out validatedToken);
```

Anyone know why it's not working ? I also tried to don't load keys by myself thinking that JwtSecurityTokenHandler may be able to do it by it self but it's not working as well.

When I load this token on jwt.io it says it is validated...

Comment: JWS? Do you mean JWT? Or is JWS a variant?

Comment: Yes I mean JWT but according to what I read I receive a variant named JWS. it mean that it is signed

Comment: What happens if you just enter a random key in `X509SecurityKey` as parameter? Since you have `TryAllIssuerSigningKeys` it shouldn't affect your jwt token without `kid`.

Comment: same error if I specified only one key...

Comment: Sorry; I meant as key **identifier**. E.g. `new X509SecurityKey(cert, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())` or `new X509SecurityKey(cert) { KeyId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }`.

Comment: Where would we expect the `kid`? -- I am no expert, especially with using own certificates - but when using an external provider you can access the keys through the `.well-known` endpoints. Of course we don't have that, but should the key be embedded in the certificate? If so - has it the correct format? And: how are you validating with jwt.io? Maybe it helps to put the JWT json here as well.